# Clearing out the R workspace

Tags: r

When trying to clear out an R workspace, why does code snippet #1 work, but not #2

Snippet #1

```
rm(list = ls())
```

Snippet #2

```
list = ls()
rm(list)
```

Comment: those are not equivalent... I think what you want to do is: `rm(list=list)` since `rm(list)` just removes an object named `list`.

Comment: Ok, so if I am understanding this right, you need to pass the first "list" lets R know that we are passing a list and the second one is the list that's being passed , is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

Because you are not naming the argument (i.e. the `list=` part of the command), R interprets `list` as an *object to be removed*, not a *list of arguments to be removed*: from `?rm`:

> `rm    (..., list = character(), pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos), inherits = FALSE)`
>
> **Arguments**
>
> `...`  the objects to be removed, as names (unquoted) or character strings (quoted)
>
> `list`    a character vector naming objects to be removed.

(This would be true even if you called the variable something else, e.g. `junk = ls(); rm(junk)` vs. `rm(list=junk)`)